# select value from a drop down for angular application without select tag in selenium webdriver

Tags: angularjs, selenium, automation

See the above code and help me to select IBM Software training from the dropdown.I got stuck on this issue for past 1 week. As the front end is made in angular and there is no select tag, so I am unable to select the dropdown.I don't have selenium IDE installed on my laptop as I am using Firefox version 52.Selenium IDE is not available for higher version.So, really helpless.Please help me out to resolve this issue.

```
              <div class="cdk-overlay-container"><div class="cdk-overlay-backdrop cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop cdk-overlay-backdrop-showing"></div>
    <div id="cdk-overlay-3" class="cdk-overlay-pane" dir="ltr" style="min-width: 503px; pointer-events: auto; top: 108.422px; left: 209px;">
          <div class="mat-select-panel mat-primary mat-select-panel-done-animating" style="transform-origin: 50% 24px 0px; opacity: 1; min-width: calc(100% + 32px); transform: scaleY(1);">
            <div class="mat-select-content" style="opacity: 1;">

                  <!---->
<md-option role="option" tabindex="0" id="md-option-99" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false" class="mat-option"><!---->
            IBM Software training3
</md-option>
<md-option role="option" tabindex="0" id="md-option-100" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false" class="mat-option"><!---->
            IBM Software training1
</md-option>
<md-option role="option" tabindex="0" id="md-option-101" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false" class="mat-option"><!---->
            New Category
</md-option>
<md-option role="option" tabindex="0" id="md-option-102" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false" class="mat-option"><!---->
            IBM SOftware trainingggggg
</md-option>
<md-option role="option" tabindex="0" id="md-option-103" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false" class="mat-option"><!---->
            IBM Software training
</md-option>
<md-option role="option" tabindex="0" id="md-option-104" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false" class="mat-option"><!---->
           qqq
</md-option>
    <md-option role="option" tabindex="0" id="md-option-105" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false" class="mat-option"><!---->
            eeeee

</md-option>
<md-option role="option" tabindex="0" id="md-option-106" aria-
    selected="false" aria-disabled="false" class="mat-option"><!---->
                New
</md-option>
<md-option role="option" tabindex="0" id="md-option-
        107" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false" class="mat-option"><!---->
                Economics
</md-option>
<md-option role="option" tabindex="0" id="md-option-108" aria-
    selected="false" aria-disabled="false" class="mat-option"><!---->
               IBM
</md-option>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div></div>
```

Comment: Please, share the elaborated HTML. Thi HTML is just showing 4 options. It is not showing any dropdown.

Comment: Hey, you can the value IBM in dark black font, they all are dropdown values with md-option tag.I want to click on the IBM value by using Selenium locators, but unable to it .I tried XPath and cssSelectors also but was unable to click on the value

Comment: As I think these <md-option> is not the real DOM element for dropdown item, there will be some hidden elements that appear each time you click to show the dropdown.

Comment: @Anjali, the HTML you have shared is not giving any info of dropdown. Can you please share the elaborated HTML.

Comment: <md-option role="option" tabindex="0" id="md-option-101" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false" class="mat-option">

New Category

</md-option>

Comment: @monica Is this ohk or something i have to share?

Comment: @monica Look at the above code .Is it ohk now .So ,can u pls help me with the solution

Comment: @Anjali: You dropdown is using mat-ripple. This HTML will not help me. You will have to share your URL so that I can help you.

Comment: @AnjaliSingh Can you consider showcasing your work and a bit more of the relevant HTML DOM please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems a unique id is assigned to all the options. Did you try clicking on the option using id?

Comment: They all change after each time I refresh the page , they are dynamic

Comment: Try below code -
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='mat-select-content']//md-option[text()='IBM Software training']")).click();

Comment: This way will open my dropdown , but unable to click on the value

Comment: WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='mat-select-content']//md-option[text()='New Category']")); 
Thread.sleep(5000);
 action.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
  This is my code and the error is  org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='mat-select-content']//md-option[text()='New Category']"}

Comment: WebElement check=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//md-select[@placeholder='Category name']")); 
  check.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement checknew=check.findElement(By.xpath("//md-option[text()='New Category']"));
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        checknew.click();

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='mat-select-content']//md-option[text()='New Category']")).click();
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: hey,it is opening my dropdown list but not clicking on the value New Category.

Comment: can you pls share the screen shot.. I think some wait need to be given.

Comment: I tried by giving Thread.sleep and used movetoElement also,but not working

Answer (score 0):

You could try to select it somehow like this

```
"//mat-option[contains(., \"" + variableName + "\")]"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xpath = //md-option[text() = 'IBM Software training']
```

I hope this helps.

You must click the dropdown field prior to click on dropdown value, then all dropdown values are present in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The things is that depending on the version of angular you are using, the solution will vary in the implementation details. they both share the same flow though.

1st, you need to click on the mat-select (or md-select), doing so will have the dropbox down being populated.

now, instead of using a thread.sleep, you should instead check if angular has any pending http_requests (angular 1) or if the _ngZone is stable (angular 2). I do not have the exact syntax at hand as I am replying from my phone, but I am confident that you can look up those here.

Once the loading part is done, then you issue the click on the option element.

be wary that if the drop-down list is very long, you may need to scroll down to the element that needs to be clicked.